# Cookie is not sent on android 4.1.2 webview

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a method that sets and saves a Session Cookie for Android WebView. This code lets me to send a cookie with request that goes by loading url into webview. Unfortunately its not sent on device with android 4.1.2.

```
private void handleSessionCookieFromWebView() {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (sessionCookie != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        }
        else {
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookies(null);
        }
        String cookieString = JSESSION_ID + sessionCookie.getValue();
        cookieManager.setCookie(sessionCookie.getDomain(), cookieString);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(FunctionActivity.this);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }
        else {
        cookieManager.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I call it before loading URL into WebView. Any ideas what's the problem? Maybe some kind of workaround?